# How would I use a JS drop cut date to auto fill a text area

Tags: php, javascript, html

How do I automatically fill the text field below with the selected date? Making it fill it in automaticly.

[image]

```
<td width = "370" class = "style22">
    <input name = "date" type = "text" id = "date" value = "<?php echo $current_date ?>" size="20">
    <select id = "daydropdown"> </select>
    <select id = "monthdropdown"> </select>
    <select id = "yeardropdown"> </select>                    
    <script type = "text/javascript">

        // populatedropdown(id_of_day_select, id_of_month_select, id_of_year_select)
        window.onload = function(){ 
            populatedropdown("daydropdown", "monthdropdown", "yeardropdown")
        }
    </script>
</td>
```

Comment: I want it to auto fill the text box when you select a different date

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `selectedIndex` property of `<select> ... </select>` HTML element. You may use it to access currently selected option.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showDate(){
    // Get all <select>'s to array.
    // You may change their positions in array, if needed.
    var combos = [
        document.getElementById('daydropdown'),
        document.getElementById('monthdropdown'),
        document.getElementById('yeardropdown')
    ];

    var values = [], combo, value;

    for(var i = 0; i < combos.length; i++){
        // current <select> element:
        combo = combos[i];

        // value of selected <option> for current <select>:
        value = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].innerHTML;

        // push value to buffer
        values.push(value);
    }

    // assignment of <input>'s value:
    document.getElementById('date').value = values.join(' ');
}

// event handlers:
document.getElementById('daydropdown').onchange =
   document.getElementById('monthdropdown').onchange =
       document.getElementById('yeardropdown').onchange = showDate;
</script>
```

Comment: +1 this is the right path. you need to monitor the state of each select input and build the string out yourself. If you want to format the date output differently, I'd have your select input values be numeric and create a date object out of them. Then use SugarJS, or some other tool, to format the date as desired.

Comment: @loesak Yeah, thanks. Formatting is really locale-depenedent. There also might be another way: `document.getElementById('date').value = values[2] + ' ' + values[1] + ' ' + values[0];`.